# Rails 4 Javascript: Having trouble with image paths

Tags: javascript, image, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, relative-path

I'm trying to get the background image to change every 6 seconds and it's always a 404 error:

For example, the below appears in the JS console

```
http://localhost:3000/app/assets/images/ggb_mist.png 404 (Not Found)
```

To simplify this I just tried a `background-color` to make sure it was working. See below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function testing() {
    $('.holder').css('background-color', 'red');
  };
});
```

The above works. Now when I try to do the same with an image (which is located in `app/assets/images/imagefilenamehere.png` I always get a 404 error. I've tried:

```
filenamehere.png
../assets/images/filenamehere.png
../app/assets/images/filenamehere.png
../images/filenamehere.png
```

Why won't the below work?

```
$('.holder').css({'backgroundImage':'../assets/images/filenamehere.png'});
```

Any input on the matter is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solved my problem: [Section 2.3.1 of guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

```
$('.holder').css("background-image","url(<%= asset_path('tree-rays.jpg') %>)");
```

Note that `tree-rays.jpg` is in app/assets/images (Rails 4 Application).

Comment: That worked for me, instead of tranquilize's answer. The key was having the url(...) around the ruby expression, and using a comma instead of a colon.

Comment: this is the best solution ever, but I think you can't use asset_path in .js file.. so what about that?

Answer (score 21):

You can use the `.erb` (embedded ruby) extension to allow rails path helpers in your `.js` files:

1) You save your original file (`my_script.js`) as `my_script.js.erb` with the image path helper:

```
$('.holder').css({"background-image":"<%= asset_path('filenamehere.png') %>"});
```

Also, make sure you have your asset pipeline set up correctly:

From the Rails Asset Pipeline guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

2) Your javascript file (`my_script.js.erb`) is inside:

```
app/assets/javascripts/
lib/assets/javascripts/
vendor/assets/javascripts/
vendor/assets/somepackage/
```

3) Your file is referenced in the manifest (maybe `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`):

```
//= require my_script
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. the file was initially `welcome.js.coffee` so i commented out the coffee gem and made the file `welcome.js`. Now I've changed it to `welcome.js.erb` and applied the jQuery above. My `application.js` is indeed in `app/assets/javascripts/` and `//=require welcome` in `application.js` doesn't change anything. No errors in js console (I can get an alert to work).

Comment: Sweet got it: See here section 2.3.1 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html . Upvote for you though as you were basically right.