# how do I change the source of image_tag helper using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am using Image_tag helper and the assets pipeline from rails, this way:

```
<%= image_tag "win_jorge_start_0.jpg", :id => "image0" %>
```

I am trying to change the source of the image_tag using JQuery like this:

```
$('#image0').attr( "src" , "win_jorge_complete_0.jpg" );
```

the src of the image is changed as expected:

```
<img alt="Win jorge start 0" src="win_jorge_complete_0.jpg" id="image0">
```

but the source path is not completed as it is when using the Image_tag helper:

```
<img alt="Win jorge start 0" src="/assets/win_jorge_start_0-51b6339e1e0a021aa878ee8b54cb957a.jpg" id="image0">
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps change the html of the parent container to contain the image tag as html?

Comment: this wouldn't be an option since I still want to use the image_tag helper. changing the image_tag for a normal html img tag and providing the full image path would for sure work, but I would like to keep the image_tag helper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your JavaScript use:

```
$('#image0').attr( "src" , "<%= image_path "win_jorge_start_0.jpg", :id => "image0" %>" );
```

also see: 
[AssetUrlHelper#image_path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_path)

Comment: your answer works perfect, I just had to change the extension of the javascript file from "abc.js" to "abc.js.erb" to allow rails path helpers in .js files as answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22029184/432424

Comment: well, I'm not a rails programmer. :-D I read some documents and just got lucky. ;-) I'm happy that it was helpful.