# Passing an image filename to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a Rails v4.2 website.

I have a JavaScript object that takes the name of an image file as a property:

```
var obj = new objects.Factory.MyObject({
    title: 'Sir',
    education: 'Phd',
    icon: './profile.png'
  });
```

I placed my images in "app/assets/images", however when I load the page, I see a 404 error when trying to retrieve the image.

I tried using `image_tag` which obviously did not work in Javascript. How may I correctly specify the path of an image in a Javascript code section of a Rails page?

Comment: I think what your looking for is described in this SO  question / answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028842/rails-4-javascript-having-trouble-with-image-paths

Answer (score 2):

I would rename your JavaScript file by appending a `.erb` to the end of the extension, and then load your `assets/images` with the following line in your JavaScript file:

```
<%= asset_path('profile.png') %>
```